# Why is the susceptibility the second derivative of energy with respect to field?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics

where does this result come from
$$\chi=\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial^2 \vec E}$$
where E is electric field and H is energy.

Comment: Where did you find this formula ?

Answer (score 1):

Second derivatives in thermodynamics come from deriving other parameters.

$$\chi_e=\dfrac{\partial^2 H}{\partial E^2}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial E}\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial E}=\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{P}}{\partial E}$$

The first derivative is the polarization. Then, you derive with respect to the electric field. Polarization and electric field are related, by definition, by the susceptibility.

Comment: why is polarization the first derivative of energy?

Comment: I am assuming that the fundamental relation's diferential is $dU=TdS - PdV + \mu dN + \mathcal{P}dE$.